# SOAP API: PHP Code doesn't work, but SOAP UI works

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to create a rental module for my work's website. When I use the same parameters in SmartBear's SOAP UI, it works. So, I'm assuming that it's something to do with my code, but I cannot find the error.

```
<?php //Submit Reservation
require("connect.php");
$sessionId = $_SESSION['sessionId'];
$moveInDate = date("yy-m-d", strtotime($_POST['moveIn']));
$billDate = date("d", strtotime($_POST['moveIn']));
$rentalOptions = array(
    "customer.company" =>$company,
    "account.startDate"=> $moveInDate,
    "contact.firstName"=>$_POST['fname'],
    "contact.lastName"=>$_POST['lname'],
    "contact.companyName"=>$_POST['companyName'],
    "contact.street1"=>$_POST['street'],
    "contact.street2"=>"",
    "contact.city"=>$_POST['city'],
    "contact.state"=>$_POST['state'],
    "contact.zip"=>$_POST['zip'],
    "contact.country"=>"US",
    "phone.1" => $_POST['mobile'],
    "contact.email"=>$_POST['email'],
    "account.currency"=>"1",
    "account.billDay"=> $billDate,
    "user.paymentMethod"=>"1",
    "user.draftDay"=>"",
    "unit.id"=>$_POST['unit-name'],
    "postAccount"=>"Y",
    "promotionId"=>$_POST['promo'],
    "insuranceId"=>$_POST['insurance']
    );
var_dump($rentalOptions);

echo "<br/>". $sessionId ."<br/><a href=\"teststorage.php\">Return</a>";

$client = new SoapClient("https://api.doorswap.com/service/system.wsdl");

// Make API Call
    $dsReceiver = "customer";
    $dsAction = "saveNewCustomer";
    $result = $client->makeReceiverCall($sessionId, $dsReceiver, $dsAction, $rentalOptions);
    //if($result["success"] == "true") {    
    //}
?>
```

The var_dump() and print_r() displays correct variables from the previous form. In fact, ALL variables are correctly output. I just do not understand WHY it isn't working. It's not giving me an error, it's just not POSTING.

FYI: I have tried using javascript SOAP and I run into similar issues. The code is right, the variables are correct, but the addition to the system is not going through.

I'm open to trying anything.

Comment: I've only stumbled through soap a few times, but what if you construct your parameters like an array keyed by the WSDL param names `$client->makeReceiverCall( array( 'sessionKey' => $sessionId, 'dsReceiver' => ... ) )`

Comment: @Scuzzy, nope.  Doesn't seem to have worked.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

### Initialization of the SoapClient class

First of all inialize your soap client the right way. The soap client class takes several options to debug your application. In the following example a soap client is initalized with some options, that will make your life more easy when testing.

```
try {
     $client = new SoapClient('https://api.doorswap.com/service/system.wsdl', [
         'exceptions' => true,
         'trace' => true,
     ]);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault->getMessage());

    if ($client instanceof SoapClient) {
        var_dump(
            $client->__getLastRequest(),
            $client->__getLastResponse()
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see the soap client class is initialized with different option parameters. The `exception` option is set to true so that the soap client class throws exceptions, when an error occurs. That 's why the code is wrapped in a try and catch block. The `trace` option allows us to see, what the last request and response looks like. If the soap client was initialized you can use the build in methods `__getLastRequest()` and `__getLastResponse()` to see what the sent and received xml looks like. Keep in mind, that these can be empty if the xml wasn 't compiled by the client.

Answer (score 0):

The makeReceiverCall method was a "name"/"value" system.  So the above array of $rentalOptions SHOULD have been done as such.  This is currently working, and has been flawless in execution.

```
$rentalOptions = array(
    array("name"=> "customer.company","value"=> $company),
    array("name"=> "account.startDate", "value"=> $moveInDate),
...
);
```

This was the error that I had run into and finally figured out.  Thank you to all those who tried to help.